# Determining the upper bounds and lower bounds of the price of commodity and total sales?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics

Suppose that $P$, the price of a certain commodity (in
dollars), and $S$, its total sales (in $10,000$ units), are random
variables whose joint probability distribution can be
approximated closely with the joint probability density

$$f(p,s) = 
\begin{cases}
5pe^{-ps} , & \text{for }  .20<p <.40,s>0\\[2ex]
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Find the probabilities that

$(a)$ the price will be less than $30$ cents and sales will
exceed $20,000$ units

---

In order to solve this problem one must first use some analytical skills. For example,

$100$ cents = $\$1.00$ dollar

$30$ cents = $\$0.30$ cents

We know that $(P<.30, S>20,000)= \int^{.30}_{.20}5pe^{-ps} dp $

But now here is where I get stuck how does one identify $S =\{ \text{total sales} \}$. I do not know how to do this I can only add my conjecture which I believe should be

$\int_{20,000}^{\infty}$

If I combine this with the above would this be a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that the units in S are in 10 000. So in order for it to be bigger than 20 000, it has to be bigger than $2\cdot 10000$.

$P(P<0.3,S> 20000 )=\int_2^\infty \int_{0.2}^{0.3} f(p,s)dp ds$.

Comment: Why do you use 2 instead of 20000 as you have proposed above? Are you converting units to another measuring system?

Comment: It is from the problem text you provided. It says that S is given in 10 000, så if S = 1, it means 10 000, S = 1.2 means 12 000, S = 2 means 20 000,etc.

Comment: In my opinion there is a big difference between 2 and 20000. I guess it is one of those things one must infer as a mathematician.